# How to prevent other users from accessing PHP source code?

Tags: php

The source code of my website is on a server multiple people can access via FTP.

How can I prevent them from accessing the source code?

**Edit:**

Ok, so I can't do nothing about that. But, how about if I can compress the script and to change with the original on FTP? (of course in my PC will not be compressed the code). But how can I compress all the codes if I have for example like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
<a href="<?php echo Config::$_PAGE_URL; ?>complaints">General complaints</a>
</div>
<?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
    $data = 1;?>
       <a href="<?php echo Config::$_PAGE_URL; ?>mycomplaints">My complaints</a> <?php
    }
?>
<script>
function showpictures(x, y) {
    swal.resetDefaults()
    var token_id = '<?php echo config::$GeneralToken ?>';
    swal('Coords','<img src = "'+page_url+'maps?x='+x+'&y='+y+'" height = "420px"></img>','')
}
</script>

<style>
.swal2-popup {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}
</style>
```

If I can compress, can I compress all in or should I compress them separately (HTML, PHP, JS)?

Comment: You need to configure different users with different rights on files/directories.

Comment: They are with $$, and I'm with the scripting. And probably they want to have acces on their FTP. Here is the problem, I don't want for them to have my original files with source of the website/pages. Is there a way to crypt some files like that? All the acces (configure different users rights on files/directories) is given to another friend, and so lets say that he will change the rights on files, but IF he when i'm offline, change back the rights on files and stole my files, what should I do then? So that's way I need to do something, crypt or idk.

Comment: Just don't do it.

Comment: Spaghetti code would be the most inefficient option here, it is recommended to protect it with some license.

Comment: You can only obfuscate the file, and it can always be deobfuscated. So no, short answer, "crypting" the file is not possible.

Comment: There are encoders out there that could obfuscate and in addition to that, restrict the code from being run if it is uploaded on another server. (Based on MAC address which can be spoofed or IP address). I've got to add that I never tried to bypass this specific mechanism. Ultimately it's about adding extra layers to protect your code, in the end anything can be reverse engineered.

Comment: I agree with @tungsten. If you have to go this route, protect your code with an appropriate license beforehand.

Comment: @TrynaLearnSomethin This comment is really not helpful. Neither does it ask for clarification, nor does it in any other way add anything meaningful.

Comment: i edited the message, please read again

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on the way the permissions of the server are set up.

For example, the FTP server can be configured so that different users have access to different directories. You could, for instance, only allow the user `dev` to access `/var/www`, while the user `otherguy` only has access to `/home/otherguy`.